# Rails + Devise: Rememberable vs. Non-Rememberable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a Rails application using Devise, and I'm a little confused as to how Devise Rememberable works. I have `:rememberable` enabled in my User model. When I go to log in WITHOUT checking the Remember me? box, I'm still logged even after a browser close AND a computer restart.

If this is a case, what is the point of rememberable? Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: You're not missing anything. Without checking the checkbox you should be logged out after closing and re-opening the browser. Something's wrong.

Comment: Under `config/initializers/session_store.rb`, there is a line that ends in `expire_after: 504.hours`. Would that be affecting it?

Comment: I tried removing the file and restarting the server, but it's still storing a cookie that expires in 3 weeks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `expire_after: 504.hours` from `config/initializers/session_store.rb` seemes to have solved the problem, rather than removing the file altogether.

Source: [how to clear devise session on browser close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941806/devise-end-session-browser-close)